# React app compiles successfully and works but after reloading the page in the browser I get a TypeError var.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, filtering, react-functional-component

As the title says, when writing code, the app compiles and works **but when I reload the browser page I get an error**. `countries` is the response data from https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all and should be an array of objects if I'm not crazy? Does anybody have an idea? I'm clueless at this point.

I only get the app working if I comment out the code that produces the error (`let filteredCountries = count...` and the `List` component that uses it), then let the app compile, remove the comments and let it compile again. At this point everything works, but after reloading there's this error (in the browser. My terminal says compiled successfully).

```
TypeError: countries.filter is not a function
Countries
src/components/Countries/Countries.js:25
  22 |     setFilter(event.target.value);
  23 | };
  24 | 
> 25 | let filteredCountries = countries
     | ^  26 |     .filter((country) => {
  27 |         return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
  28 |     })
```

**This is my component:**

```
const Countries = () => {
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            // npm run server
            .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
            .then((response) => {
                setCountries(response.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);

    const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
        setFilter(event.target.value);
    };

    // HERES THE ERROR LINE
    let filteredCountries = countries
        .filter((country) => {
            return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
        })
        .slice(0, 10);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Countries</h1>
            filter: <input value={filter} onChange={handleFilterChange} />
            <List filteredCountries={filteredCountries} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Countries;
```

**This is a clipping from `response.data`:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "topLevelDomain": [".af"],
        // ...
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [{ "acronym": "SAARC", "name": "South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation", "otherAcronyms": [], "otherNames": [] }],
        "cioc": "AFG"
    },
    {
        "name": "Åland Islands",
        "topLevelDomain": [".ax"],
        // ...
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
        "regionalBlocs": [{ "acronym": "EU", "name": "European Union", "otherAcronyms": [], "otherNames": [] }],
        "cioc": ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intialize const countries with empty array:

```js
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint gives an array of objects, yes - but your initial state is *not*, it's the empty string, which is the problem:

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState('');
```

Change to

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
```

Comment: I accepted the other guys answer though, because he posted first. I'm new to SO and hope you understand.